# Add UISearchBar programmatically to a programmatically added UITableView in a normal ViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a very special request. No tutorial or already asked questions worked for me due to not the same scenario. Its special because i want to enhance an existing app without reprogramming all of the code.

I want to programmatically add a UISearchbar.
The Searchbar should be added to a UITableView which is programmatically added too.

This all takes place in a normal UIViewController.

My current approach displays the Searchbar but it does not search within my UITableView.
Simply nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

```
myTableView    =   [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
searchBar.delegate = self;

myTableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

UISearchDisplayController *searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
searchController.delegate = self;

myTableView.dataSource      =   self;
myTableView.delegate        =   self;

[self.view addSubview:myTableView];
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your object implementing the delegate methods in [UISearchDisplayDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchDisplayDelegate)?

In other words, you have to define what happens when text is entered in the search bar, it does not happen automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making sure your ViewController conforms to UISearchBarDelegate, like so :

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
```

you should implement the following method

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    // do search here
}
```